# Project tango can not start

Tags: android, google-project-tango

I want to upgrade my Tango , so I clicked **setting->About tablet->System update**

when the update almost done , it show me "set_metadata_recursive: some changes failed" message , so I shut down and select recovery mode I choose **wipdata/factory reset**

when I reboot system , it can not start again , What can I do now ? Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

When you said, you mean you can't start the devices?
or you saw the tango icon, but fail to get into the system?

But it seem your android image is gone,
If factory data reset won't work, 
contact project-tango-help@google.com  for help.

Comment: Yes , I can see the tango icon but fail to get into the system . After I press the power button try to load the android a while , it get into the recovery mode , not to system, is the android image gone ?